# Kuratowski's closure-complement theorem modification

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Everyone knows that in a topological space, the number of distinct subspaces which can be obtained using only closures and complements is $14$.

What's the number of non-homeomorphic spaces we can obtain this way? What about non-homotopic? What if we require the spaces to be (separable) metrizable?

As @mathematrucker said in the comments, [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01104479) shows an example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which gives the maximum of $34$ subspaces obtained using the operations of closure, complement and boundary, all of which are not homeomorphic. The example is $$M = \{0\}\cup \bigcup_{j=1}^{10} [j, j+\frac{1}{2}]\cup (\mathbb{Q}\cap \bigcup_{j=10}^{200} (j, j+\frac{1}{2}))\cup [1000, 2001]\setminus \{1001, 1002, ..., 2000\}$$ and in particular it gives us $14$ non-homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ using only closures and complements, and $9$ non-homotopic. This gives the answer to my first question.

Comment: The standard 14 example isubspace lies in a separable metrisable space ($\Bbb R$) and all 14 subspaces are mutually non-homeomorphic IIRC. So the answer remains 14. The question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what's unclear about my question? If I don't know what needs explaining, how should I explain it?

Comment: "Closure and Boundary Operators in Topological Spaces" by Ĭ. Z. Kleĭner (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01104479) concludes with a subset of the reals that generates 34 nonhomeomorphic subsets under closure, complement, and boundary.  Since all such subsets generate 14 sets under closure and complement, this example covers the case you are asking about.

Comment: btw I like your question.  AFAIK Kleiner's the only author to address it explicitly in the literature.

Comment: I meant it’s clear that we *can* obtain 14 different subsets from closure and complement. It’s a provable max which gives rise to 14 non-homeomorphic subspaces. So I don’t see what you remaining question is. All is known already.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I disagree that it's clear or that it's all known. Maybe in some circles it is, but not for me, hence the question. Besides, is it clear that $14$ such subspaces exist which aren't homotopic? It seems like a completely new question to me.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the question asks for a stronger result than the Kuratowski closure-complement theorem. Your claim that it follows trivially from Kuratowski's theorem is unsubstantiated.